# F# on macOS - Fake fails to build

Tags: f#, macos-high-sierra, f#-fake

I am getting an error when trying to build a simple F# project on macOS High Sierra.

```
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 5.0.1.1 (2017-02/5077205 Sun Sep 17 18:29:46 BST 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

Steps:

1. Open VS Code
2. Ionide New F# Project
3. Choose the Suave Project Template
4. `$ mono .paket/paket.exe install`
5. `$ ./build.sh`

The error is:

```
1) System.Exception: dotnet build failed
at FSI_0005.Build+runDotnet@40.Invoke (System.String message) [0x00001] in <c9993ec69ddb4848af99438005012ea7>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl+StringPrintfEnv`1[TResult].Finalize () [0x00012] in <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl+Final1@224[TState,TResidue,TResult,A].Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] env, A a) [0x00038] in <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.OptimizedClosures+Invoke@3253[T2,TResult,T1].Invoke (T2 u) [0x00001] in <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0 
at FSI_0005.Build.runDotnet (System.String workingDir, System.String args) [0x00048] in <c9993ec69ddb4848af99438005012ea7>:0 
at FSI_0005.Build+clo@64-6.Invoke (System.String p) [0x0000a] in <c9993ec69ddb4848af99438005012ea7>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Iterate[T] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] action, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x0002d] in <5893d081904cf4daa745038381d09358>:0 
at FSI_0005.Build+clo@62-5.Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit _arg4) [0x0000b] in <c9993ec69ddb4848af99438005012ea7>:0 
at Fake.TargetHelper+targetFromTemplate@209-1[a].Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar0) [0x00001] in <59b649fdccf1c534a7450383fd49b659>:0 
at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget (Fake.TargetHelper+TargetTemplate`1[a] target) [0x0004b] in <59b649fdccf1c534a7450383fd49b659>:0
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Ionide did not pick the correct target framework by default.

You need to make the following changes:

1. To `*.fsproj`, change the target framework to:

   ```
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
   ```
2. To `paket.dependencies`, change the framework to:

   ```
   framework: >= netcoreapp2.0
   ```

Run Paket again:

```
$ mono .paket/paket.exe install
```

Run the build script again:

```
$ ./build.sh
```